# Is there a simple way to "brighten" or "darken" a color?

Tags: color

For example, I have color `#009b55` (ForestGreen), and I want to get a slightly brighter version of it - `#00a85c`. Is there a function that can do it for me?

Comment: @JohnWickerson - but can I use "ForestGreen!20!black" ?

Comment: @JohnWickerson - yes, it seems I can. Thanks! If you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: An aside: "dimmen" isn't actually an English word. You probably wanted "darken" `;)`.

Comment: If you got the HTML color value already it’s also possible to use `\color[HTML]{00a85c}` or `\definecolor{MyGreen}{HTML}{00a85c}` to define a new color named `MyGreen` …

Comment: @Tobi - yes, that's also helpful. But in my case, I wanted to automate color conversion - the original color came from macro argument. So John's suggestion works perfectly.

Comment: @JohnWickerson: You mean "dim" :)

Comment: @Rogach: I know but I thought it could be a helpful notice for other users finding the question ;-)

Comment: @JohnWickerson - I edited it to darken now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you put

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

in your preamble, you can write things like

```
ForestGreen!60!black
```

to get a colour that is 60% ForestGreen and 40% black. ("Forest Green" is made available through the `dvipsnames`<sup>([reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips))</sup> option.)

See [(TikZ or xcolor) lighten color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48663/25356) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: You can also do this with a reference to the current colour, for example \color{blue} Blue \color{.!80!black} Darker